# How can I present values of <h:selectManyCheckbox> in an input field?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm creating a website that is using jsf, html, java, and JavaDB. One of my pages will list a number of images that represents menus a customer can select. At the bottom of the page there are a `selectManyCheckbox` with the options corresponding with the images. When a customer has selected a combination of menus, an "Order" button would guide the customer to the next page. On this page there are listed additional information about the customer (retrieved from the database) such as: `Customer number`, `Contact name`, etc. In additional to that the selected menu should be listed in the table, and the number of row listed should be the same as the number of menus selected. My main problem is that I want to use the data collected from the `selectManyCheckbox` as my input in the selected menu field, and the rest is collected from the database (That I have done and it works). How can I get the values as separate values? I am only able to use them in a output  text and not as values in a input field.

Java code:

```
        @Named
        @RequestScoped
        public class OrderBean implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Set<String> menus = new TreeSet<String>();

        public Set<String> getMenus() { 
           return menues;
        }

        public void setMenus(Set<String> newValue){
           menus = newValue;
        }

        public SelectItem[] getMenuesItems(){
           return menuesItems;
        }

        private static SelectItem[] menuesItems = {
           new SelectItem("Menu 1"),
           new SelectItem("Menu 2"),
           new SelectItem("Menu 3")
        };
   }
```

JSF, HTML:

```
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div id="frame">
        <div id="frameCheckBox"><h:commandButton value="#{mld.Order}" action="Order"/>
             <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{orderBean.menus}">
                  <f:selectItems value="#{orderBean.menusItems}"/>
             </h:selectManyCheckbox>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? You have already the selected values into the server side, in `menues` set, so what do you want to do with that?

Comment: I think there might be an English language communication issue here... do you mean a list of items? or is the user really purchasing several menus (for their restaurant maybe... Menus are lists of items, usually with prices and descriptions/photos)

Comment: The delivery address and date are typed in by the customer, but the information of the selected menu should be collected from the previous page and inserted for them. This information is then send and stored in the database as Orders registered to the customer. The problem is that I can't get the information from the selectManyCheckbox as individual variables to plot in to the "Total order list" before its sent to the database. I can only get them as output (all at once) but not as input in a new field. Maybe I am doing it totally wrong and cumbersome.

Comment: I'm thinking more like an Array. If the person has selected two of three options, the number of rows is two, and then I could use the .get(index) to collect the selected menu1  .get(1) and menu2 .get(2). in the table displayed for the customer before the order is sent. But I'm really new at this and don't know exactly how to implement this feature.

Comment: The reason it should be individual rows for each selected menu is that the customer should be able to add the number of people that want that menu (order for conferances with many people) and that is used to calculate the total price, delivery cost and VAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Set<String>` by `List<String>` or `String[]`, so that you can generate the desired input components with help of an `<ui:repeat>` as follows:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{orderBean.menus}" varStatus="loop">
    <h:inputText value="#{orderBean.menus[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Like `<h:dataTable>`, it namely doesn't support `Set` until the upcoming JSF 2.2. Please also note that you really need to reference the input value by list/array index instead of via `<ui:repeat var>`, for the simple reason that `String` is immutable and doesn't have a setter method.

Last but not least, this construct will fail during processing the form submit as your bean is request scoped and thus gets garbaged directly after the form is presented to the enduser. Put it in a bit wider scope, e.g the view, conversation or perhaps the session scope. Otherwise JSF won't be able to set the submitted values in the initial list/array.

Comment: Thanks! 
I have just started with JSF and the method and its ways is not in my fingertips yet :P